# Properties in auto generated NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have the following property which is created from an auto generated `NSManagedObject`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id imageViewBounds;
```

Which is synthesized as `dynamic` in the .m file. Is it OK to change this to:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGRect imageViewBounds;
```

without worrying about experiencing any crazy side effects? Seems to work OK, but having trouble understanding if this will lead to any unintended consequences with the `dynamic` variable.

Comment: How is this property declared in your model? Structs aren't directly supported in core data.

Comment: Yeah have to convert NSValue it seems if you want to put that as the answer go ahead @jrturton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting that it even works at all.

If the standard objects for Core Data are not to your liking, you should set the property to transformable in your model. This way you can guarantee that what you are doing will not give unexpected results later.

See these links on transformable objects:

```
http://www.lextech.com/2013/01/core-data-transformable-attributes/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/photolocations/introduction/intro.html
```

Though with structs, such as CGRect, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Yes this is correct, it actually wasn't working like I thought it was. I had to store the structs into NSValue and then it worked fine (I already was setting them as transformable).